# Fancybox - jQuery in onCleanup

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there a way of using jQuery inside of the onCleanup function of fancybox? I am using fancybox to handle some file uploads inside of an iframe, and I need to update some form fields when it's done uploading.

```
$('.upload-image').fancybox({
        'type':'iframe',
        'onCleanup':function(){
            alert($this);
        }
});
```

The above does not work, I tried calling a function too, but I can't seem to use any jQuery in that either:

```
$('.upload-image').fancybox({
        'type':'iframe',
        'onCleanup':somefunction
});

function somefunction(){
    alert($this);
};
```

Is there any way I can call a jquery enabled function when the fancybox window is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this should work perfectly. Maybe alerting `$this` isn't such a good idea? Have you tried wrapping your whole code in an anonymous function closure?

It could also be that you have to decline your function **before** using it elsewhere.  Does your browser give you any error message?

```
(function($){
    $(function() {

        var myfunc = function() {
            alert('fired');
        };



        $('.upload-image').fancybox({
                'type':'iframe',
                'onCleanup': myfunc()
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```